# Use of Apache JMeter for conducting http flood with an ASP.NET WebForms site

Tags: jmeter

i want to conduct an http flood to a test website that i have designed in Visual Studio 2017. It is an ASP.NET Webforms site, so i want to ask if Apache JMeter is a proper tool for such a project. I have done some research and found from other users that Apache JMeter is having some problems with ASP.NET apps in some cases. So i'm a little confused. Also, i am considering to use two computers, one for running the website, and the other for running the JMeter script, in order to avoid the resource consumption that may lead to inaccurate metrics. Is it possible to succeed the http flood in such a way? Any other suggestions are welcome.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter doesn't have any problems with ASP.NET websites (as well as any other websites), JMeter is backend-agnostic and it knows nothing about server-side technologies stack as it basically gets HTML and [Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) from the server.

Just make sure to perform [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) of dynamic parameters like [VIEWSTATE](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/225740/what-is-view-state-and-how-it-works-in-Asp-Net53/), [EVENTVALIDATION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.enableeventvalidation?view=netframework-4.7.2), etc. and you should be good to go.

With regards to "flood" approach - I would rather recommend implementing real life user scenarios, to wit JMeter test should represent real usage of your web application by the [real user using the real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) including business steps (login, browse, search, etc.) and technical side of things ([Cookies](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager), embedded resources, [headers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager), [cache](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager))

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Is it possible to do it with two computers as i mentioned above?

Comment: As long as the "computer" where your website is running configuration is similar to production environment - yes. If it differs - still yes, but up to [certain extent](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/performance-testing-scaled-down-environment-part-two-five-things-you-can-test)